# Flash Media Server (FMS) streams recording

Tags: video, flash-media-server, video-recording

I'm trying to record a FLV, using servers-side scripting. It's working as expected. I'm using record('append') to add streams to the same file. What I want to do now is record the streams in "real-time". I want to keep the same functionality (append) but I want to "records" the time that there is no streams available. In other words, I want to ends a with a file (FLV) with the srtreams separated by black frames when there are no streams available. If the time between a stream and the next stream is 5 minutes, I want the FLv to play 5 minutes in black.

Is that possible with FMS?

Answer (score 0):

Make another stream, always running on the fms. You can do it by having another client connected on the fms machnie or even use "LIve encoder". 
When you detect that your stream is off, append that stream to your file.

Good luck